# Load Images into listview

Tags: android, image, listview

Is it possible to load an image into a listview, where the path to the image is on a table?

Comment: At least try to write a correct sentence..

Comment: I dont speak very well English. Se eu falar em portugues, o que dizes ó ótario ???

Comment: Thank you Aurelio, for correct my bad English. ;)

Comment: I did not write that because of your English. I wrote that because you put no effort in your question.

Comment: C.D. Ok, i understand your point. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, it sounds like you want to display an image in a ListView using a table to control positioning, probably to do something along the lines of providing a description that accompanies the image.  It's definitely possible to use images in ListViews by leveraging a custom adapter.

Take a look at this example.  I found it very helpful when I tried to do the same thing recently:

http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-listview-with-iconsimages-and-sharks-with-lasers/

The only difference in your case is that you'll want to create a view using TableLayout view elements while this example is using a LinearLayout (see country_listitem.xml).

You'll want to make sure you create your custom view to handle the layout properties and a custom adapter to leverage that view and you'll accomplish your goal.

Comment: Thank you mchandler. I already have read that topic, but dont figure how to adapt that example to my app. And i try, believe me. Thank you.